# creating a crosstab query for my offer price list with access

Tags: crosstab

i have a table similar to bellow
| item | vendor | price |spcial                     |
|:---- |:------:| -----:|--------------------------:|
| itm1 | stc    | 15000 |vat 8%/wih wheels|
| itm1 | msb    | 15500 |vat 8%/wih out wheels|
| itm2 | msb    | 16.00 |indi/manila|
| itm2 | stc    | 15.00 |chi/imported|
| itm3 | msb    |  5000 |vat 8%/imported/6 month warranty|

i want to print it out as list like bellow
| item | stc | msb |wpb|
|:---- |:---:| ---:|--:|
| itm1 | 15000 (vat 8%/with wheels)|15500(vat 8%/wih out wheels)|-(-)|
| itm1 | 16.00 (indi/manila)   | 15.00(chi/imported) |-(-)|
| itm2 | -(-)    |-(-)  |5000(vat 8%/imported/6 month warranty)|